# Происходит языковое изменение связано с использованием творительного/именительного падежа в сказуемых составных с глаголом «быть»?

Tags: падежи, сказуемые, языковые-изменения

Насколько я понял, в сказуемых составных, есть семантическое различие между творительным падежом и именительным, с глаголом «быть». Например во фразе мы «были друзья» по сравнению с «мы были друзьями». Первый выражает более статическо.

Мне хотелось бы знать, если эти форми используются/толковаться как взаимозаменяемые, и, прежде всего, означает ли это, что русскоязычные делают часто грамматических ошибок выбрав неправильного подежа. Если это так, есть какое-то изменение поведения предпочтения определенному падежу? Например, люди начнут больше использовать творительный подеж в в таких предложениях? Это изменилось в последнее время?

Я сам изучаю Русский язык и посто заинтересован в эту тему, особенно в составе "языковые изменения". Я не мог это найти в научной литературе или в академической грамматике (e.g. Шведова, 1980). Меня особенно интересует развитие с течением времени основанное в лингвистическом литературе. Я знаю что, уже есть подобные вопросы в этом сайте.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[http://rusgram.ru/Именительный_падеж](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)

> 3.1.2. Именительный падеж в позиции именной части сказуемого В позиции именной части сказуемого именительный падеж конкурирует с творительным
> падежом (см. Творительный падеж).
>
> Форма именительного падежа употребляется тогда, когда речь идет о
> постоянном признаке, присущем носителю на протяжении длительного
> промежутка времени. Так, в приведенном примере форма творительного
> падежа является двусмысленной: ее можно понять как постоянный признак,
> т.е. ‘каждый четвертый присяжный заседатель являлся мусульманином в
> течение всей своей жизни’ или как признак временный ‘каждому
> присяжному заседателю довелось хотя бы какое-то время быть
> мусульманином’. Хотя вторая трактовка маловероятна в силу внеязыковых
> причин, с грамматической точки зрения она вполне возможна.
> Употребление именительного падежа исключает эту двусмысленность.
>
> Обычно творительный падеж в этой позиции тем вероятнее, чем более
> знаменательной является связка: при связке быть творительный падеж
> употребляется редко.
>
> Совпадение по форме подлежащего и именной части сказуемого выражает то
> обстоятельство, что соотношение справедливо для момента речи и его
> изменение в прошлом или в будущем нерелевантно (в противном случае
> употреблялось бы прошедшее или будущее время или полузнаменательная
> связка и творительный падеж). Предложения, в которых формы
> именительного падежа употребляются как в функции подлежащего, так и в
> функции сказуемого при отсутствующей связке, обнаруживают особое
> отношение к отрицанию: во многих случаях они допускают или только
> отрицательную (он тебе не пара), или только утвердительную форму (ср.
> он страшный идиот) [Падучева, Успенский 1979/2002]. В связи с этим
> некоторые исследователи предполагают, что связка в таких предложениях
> имеет особый статус. Подробная формально-синтаксическая интерпретация
> таких примеров дана в статье [Тестелец 2007]. Взаимосвязь временной
> формы связки и употребления творительного падежа рассматривалась Т.В.
> Булыгиной [Булыгина 1980]. Подробное освещение эта проблема получила в
> работах Дж. Николс (ср. [Nichols 1981], [Николс 1984]). Показательно,
> что рассмотрев разнообразные условия, влияющие на выбор формы именной
> части сказуемого, Дж. Николс приходит к выводу, что формулировка
> общего правила здесь невозможна именно из-за обилия взаимодействующих
> структурных и семантических факторов. Правила выбора падежа
> исследуются также в работе М. Гиро-Вебер [Гиро-Вебер 1996]. Пытаясь
> сформулировать закономерности такого выбора с точки зрения
> «бисинхронного» метода, автор перечисляет ряд устойчивых ограничений
> на употребление той или иной формы, а в оставшихся случаях применяет
> более дробные правила. Интуитивно оба автора понимают, что говорящие в
> процессе речепорождения используют более ‘элементарные’ механизмы
> выбора. Существенно, что в перечисленных работах речь шла как о формах
> существительных в позиции именной части сказуемого, так и о формах
> прилагательных. Статистическое исследование [Krasovitsky et al. 2008]
> показывает, что тенденции употребления падежных форм существительных в
> позиции именной части сказуемого изменяются в сторону закрепления:
> так, при темпорально или модально «нагруженной» связке употребление
> творительного падежа становится преобладающим (по данным цитируемого
> исследования, оно превышает 75%). Иными словами, неясные правила с
> течением времени сменяются господствующей в узусе тенденцией.

```
 Мне хотелось бы знать, если эти форми используются/толковаться как
 взаимозаменяемые, и, прежде всего, означает ли это, что русскоязычные
 делают часто грамматических ошибок выбрав неправильного подежа.
```

Напротив, взаимозаменяемость означает, что невозможно сделать грамматическую ошибку - и так и так будет правильно. Меняются оттенки смысла, меняется тенденции употребления в тех или иных языковых ситуациях. Но это не является ни грамматической ошибкой, ни смысловой. Вас все равно поймут как надо.

Раз уж вы заинтересованы в этой теме, то вот вам показательная задачка.
Объясните почему можно сказать

```
Он был, есть и будет человеком.
```

но нельзя сказать

```
Он есть человеком.
```